# What kind of security is needed for simple REST API on Amazon's AWS

Tags: account-security, api, aws

I am envisioning a simple REST API for my app only that essentially functions as a proxy server for some organization's API. Thus, no sensitive information is stored or available through the my API.

Critically, the information must be constantly available and accurate. It does not need to be kept confidential, as it is public information.

Amazon AWS is comparatively cheap for private hosting, but I worry that I am not addressing security concerns because I do not know what such concerns would actually be.

By security, I mean *anything* that has to do with protecting my server: some sort of firewall, strong password (of course), 2-factor authentication... I do not know what else.

Are there any security issues I should address for this simple REST API without sensitive data on AWS?

Comment: You need to start with articulating what you want to protect. Otherwise this is way too broad.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I am not exactly sure *what* I need to protect. I have no experience in the security of things like this, so I am essentially asking what types of things should be protected, if anything.

Comment: You don't need to know anything about security to answer the question. What is it you are wanting to protect? Is it personal information? Is it a service that needs a certain uptime? Does the info in it need to be accurate?

Comment: @RoryAlsop, the information needs to constantly be available and accurate. It is public, so it does not need to be kept secret.

Comment: I have edited that in - that is key information for the question, as it means we don't need to look at protecting the data from being read or leaked to the public, but instead focus on ensuring uptime/service and integrity of data

Answer (score 2):

As the most basic security principles, you need to consider the CIA triad: Confidentiality, Integrity, Availability.

Your say that the information hosted on the site is public information, so confidentiality to your company isn't priority. However, you need to consider also the user's perception of confidentiality might not necessarily be the same as your company's perception of confidentiality. Even though is public information, many people don't want their browsing habit to be tracked for various reasons, many people are searching publicly available information about medical issues they might consider embarrassing, maybe an LGBT still in the closet don't want anyone to know they're browsing certain sites that might tip other people off, maybe a husband want to hide his researching for a surprise vacation plan research from his wife. Modern best practice usually considers this to be too difficult to evaluate properly since you can't always guess the motives of your users, so end up just encrypting everything with HTTPS.

How about Integrity? How important is it that the public knows that this data is published by you, and not have been altered by any other entities? If integrity is somewhat important, then you should consider using HTTPS, and possibly also publish cryptographic signature of the data you published. How important is it that the user knows that the data is up to date? You might want to add signed timestamp of the data publication date, to ensure users can tell if they're setting outdated data (replay attack), in sine circumstances, you might even want to notarize the timestamp by publishing the hash of the data in, say, Bitcoin's blockchain.

You suggested Availability is important. Availability risks that you need to consider is attacker doing a DDOS attack to overwhelm your site, or for the attacker to trigger account lockouts by using incorrect passwords. For basic availability, you'd want to implement firewall and monitoring and alerting systems, you'd want to ensure legitimate users have a way to reset account lockout that the attacker won't be able to do. How important is it that the data is available in case of deliberate censorships like say Great Firewall of China? Depending on the level of availability that you are targeting, you may want to consider using a network of mirrors, CDN, Tor, or Freenet to distribute the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from your question that you have an API with high availability and data integrity requirements. From an infrastructure perspective you have transferred the availability concern to Amazon. Our main focus now becomes data integrity for which you need to consider the following scenarios:

1. How/from where is the data generated and populated in the system. Does your API also provide capability to make changes to the data? If not then what are the other entry points in to the system?
2. No risk can be assessed without context. You need to know who uses the data and what can go wrong if the data is altered in untended ways. This would allow you to assess the impact of a potential security issue and look at potential threats.
3. You have already mentioned that the data comes from a different source, but you need to make sure that any software/libraries used in you AWS instance is free from vulnerabilities.